# SharePoint WebPart RestAPI exception Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, sharepoint

I made a SharePoint 2013 WebPart in VisualStudio 2017 and I build a RESTapi as a console application with this tutorial:
[Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

In my WebPart I create an object from the Restapi class to use it.

```
RestAPI restApi = new RestAPI();
```

In the constructor from the RestAPI class i call the

```
RunAsync().Wait();
```

In this method i'm calling an other method.

and now my Problem:
I need to get the authentication ticket so i'm using this method:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent("username=" + lgname + ";password=" + pswd, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"/OTCS/cs.exe/api/v1/auth", content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var authResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthResponse>();
return authResponse.Ticket;
```

as an console application this works fine.

this is the AuthResponse class:

```
[JsonObject]

public class AuthResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("Ticket")]
    public string Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

I got the classes to format the JSON with http://json2csharp.com/

but when I use this in a SharePoint Webpart I get the following exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting,
>   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}
>   System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

in the .csproj file the following entry can be found:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

the formatting.dll can be found in the path.
the problem is that System.Net.Http.Formatting could not be found.
the issue is in `the await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthResponse>()`
i tried to use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(jsonString);
```

but then i get nearly the same exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"} System.Exception
>   {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

.csproj entry:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Newtonsoft.Json.dll is located in the HintPath

the app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

all the references are up to date and working when i tested it as a console application.

I'm using .NET v4.5 in the programm and in the SharePoint Server.
when i not catch the exception then i get this:

> An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   One or more errors occurred. occurred

i tried to reinstall the references but that did not work
so how can i get the references to work in the SharePoint Webpart?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webpart solution there is a package, inside the package you need to put all the assemblies (in the Advanced tab) you are going to use to add them to full trust.
[image]

Comment: Wow great! That was easy. Thank you.